# Phrase doesn't work in PdfPCell when I add PdfPCell in document

Tags: android, itext

I create a new PDF from original PDF.
I try to add Phrase in PdfPCell. The library said that when you put text in [PdfPCell](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPCell.html) you have to use Phrase.

I need to made this way because I need a position and a text in cell. I have this code.

```
mPdfFileOutPut = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            outPutFileStringBuilder.toString());
    Document document = new Document();

    try {
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(mPdfFileOutPut));
        document.open();


        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(mPdfFile);
        // Create a reader to extract info
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(is);

        // Get the fields from the reader (read-only!!!)
        AcroFields form = pdfReader.getAcroFields();



        Set<String> fields = form.getFields().keySet();


        PdfPCell cell = new  PdfPCell( new Phrase("string"));
        for (String key : fields) {
            cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.BLUE);

            cell.addElement(new Paragraph("ddfdelellelle"));
            cell.setLeft(form.getFieldPositions(key).get(0).position.getLeft());
            cell.setRight(form.getFieldPositions(key).get(0).position.getRight());
            cell.setTop(form.getFieldPositions(key).get(0).position.getTop());
            cell.setBottom(form.getFieldPositions(key).get(0).position.getBottom());
            document.add(cell);

        }
        document.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Any idea? I hope there is a solution.

Comment: The idea is to add the cells to a table, not directly to the document.

Comment: When I made this, I lost position of the cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [API documentation](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPCell.html) that you linked to, you'll see that it says: *A cell in a PdfPTable*. A table cell needs to be part of a table.

But it doesn't look like you want to use tables at all.  If I understand the intent of your code correctly, you want to create a new PDF document with text content at the same positions as the form fields in an input PDF.  Note that you're not taking into account multiple pages: if the input form has fields on more than 1 page, you'll add everything on 1 page in the output document.  You're also not taking into account page sizes.

Take a look at the convenience method `ColumnText.showTextAligned()` to add a `Phrase` with absolute positioning.  Here's an example: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=61

If you're trying to make a non-interactive version of a form, read up on *form flattening*.